# dropdown list is empty in <select>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I cannot seem to find my error, my dropdown list is empty but there are values in the array when i do a print_r($data).
My code:

```
  <?php $sql = "SELECT p.firstname, p.lastname from person p where p.personid >= :personid";
  $array = array('personid' => 75101);
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  if($sth->execute($array)) {
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
  } ?>
  <tr><td style="width:120px;">Contact Person</td>
  <td>
  <select>
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
          <option value=" <?php $key; ?>" > <?php $value ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  </td>
```

can some one help please?
thanks

Comment: missing echo for key and value

Comment: aaah i knew it was something stupid, thanks!

Comment: hi @charlie_cat hope you got solution from my ans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT p.firstname, p.lastname from person p where p.personid >= :personid";
  $array = array('personid' => 75101);
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  if($sth->execute($array)) {
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
  } ?>
  <tr><td style="width:120px;">Contact Person</td>
  <td>
  <select>
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
          <option value=" <?php echo $key; ?>" > <?php echo $value; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
      <option value=" <?php echo $key; ?>" > <?php echo $value; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant print a variable without using echo , you forgot to print the `$key` and `$value` ,

change

`<option value=" <?php $key; ?>" > <?php $value ?> </option>`

with

`<option value=" <?php echo $key; ?>" > <?php echo $value; ?> </option>`

Answer (score 0):

You are not print variables. Only use in your code.
If You need short tags, try this code:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
      <option value="<?=$key;?>"><?=$value["firstname"]." ".$value["lastname"];?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

But if on your server short tags is disabled then try code from previous replay, only `$value` variables replace with `$value["firstname"]`.